# Is claim based authorization with wcf on winXP possible?

Tags: wcf, security, windows-xp, claims

I'm currently reading a book about WIF. This technology sounds very good and fitting to our project, but unfortunately we have to support win xp...

So my question is obvious, can I use the claim based authorization with WCF without using WIF? To send the claims with the security header should not be a problem, but how can I make my own claim security token and verify that it is valid and from a valid issuer?

Thanks fro some hints and helps,
Eny

Comment: .NET 4.0 is supported on Windows XP. What's the issue?

Comment: .Net 4.0 yes, but WIF is not... claims are part of .net 4.0, but to get a signed claim token I need an IP based on WIF, or did I miss something?

Comment: You should be able to download and reference the WIF SDK from your XP application.

Comment: Yes, but not the runtime. Our application has client and server parts. The server would need the runtime right? Additionally we would have to write our own STS, which also requires the WIF runtime.

Comment: Or does .Net 4.0 already provide some STS features without WIF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You don't need WIF on the client (event though it is convenient). You just need to use right bindings (e.g. WSHTTPFederationBinding...)

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it is not only the client side I'm looking for. It does not have to be WIF, claims can also be used without WIF, but does this work together with WCF?